# Voltage stabilizing circuit

Tags: power-supply, power, capacitor

I have the following case:

- I need a stable power for esp32 at 3.3V (around 300mA) for at least
  10 seconds

Power source is:

- not DC, it is irregular
- source provides bursts of around 1.0V each second, 42W
- it can get more intensive: up to 16V with more frequent intervals (up to 1400W)

I assume I need some capacitors and diodes, but I don't know how to hook it up.

Comment: What have you tried so far? (Also, keep in mind, we know less about the circuit than you do. So you need to be as specific as possible. Qualitative descriptions are useless)

Comment: "source provides burst of around 1.0V each second" - and how much current can it deliver?

Comment: 3.3v at 300 mA "for at least 10 seconds" - and how frequently do you plan to wake-up your device? Wouldn't it be clear that you need to count average energy consumption and equate it to energy production. BTW, the general term for this activity is called "energy harvesting".

Comment: that 1.0V each second can give 42W. at more intensive cases it can get up to 1400W

Answer (score 2):

You need some capacitance, as energy storage, a harvester to charge it, and a converter to use it. And some low power control circuitry to manage the whole thing.

Your ESP32 uses about 1 watt when running. If it runs for 10 seconds, that's 10 Joules. Let's choose to use a buck converter to get between the energy store and 3.3v, so your minimum capacitor is allowed to be 4v or so, let's say 5v to give a bit of margin. Allow the capacitor to supply up to 10v, a 2:1 voltage swing uses 75% of the energy stored, a reasonable figure. So you want a capacitor that will store 13.3J at 10v. A buck converter isn't 100% efficient, so we inflate this by another 10/15% to allow for losses, to get 15J.

\$E=0.5CV^2\$ so C = 300mF (300,000uF), which is big, but not too big for a supercap. You could use a smaller value if you chose to charge to a higher voltage.

Now you need a harvester circuit, to use your 1v to 16v inputs to charge this capacitor. This is where you need a lot more information about your power source and its power capabilities. Texas Instruments do a lot of power harvesting converters, so read their application notes.

You may need some low power (read CMOS) amplifiers or references to monitor the store, to trigger the ESP32 wake-up, or to see if it's OK for it to wake up when it asks whether it can.

Notes on the energy store. You will find some fairly cheap supercaps designed for memory backup, which may not be able to deliver the 1 watt needed for your ESP32, check the power output of any you buy. You may be better off with a LiPo. Choose one large enough that swinging 15J barely changes its state of charge. This would give it very long life, NASA have found that charging their cells to a max of 3.92v allows 8year+ life in satellites in a 90 minute light/dark orbit.